# How to properly track HealthKit traditionalStrengthTraining

Tags: ios, watchkit, healthkit

I'm working on a workout app with HealthKit integration. The `HKWorkoutConfiguration`'s `activityType` is `traditionalStrengthTraining` since I'm tracking the user when he's working out using machines.

I would like to get proper HealthKit tracking. Hence my question:
Should the `HKWorkoutSession` be running during the whole workout (from first to last machine without pausing) or should I pause between machines (i.e. start the session when the user tracks working out on a certain machine and pause afterwards)?

Answer (score 1):

Keep the HKWorkoutSession running during the whole workout. If you want more accurate calorie tracking I suggest you do the calculation yourself.

You should check the [following doc from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkworkoutsession)

Only run, walk, cycle, stair climbing, elliptical, and rowing activities have customized calorie calculations from Apple.